# hackerrank question - use of proc in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, operator-keyword, proc

problem: Create a Proc p that will check whether a given array of elements are nil or not. Use .nil? to evaluate elements. Print 'true' if elements are nil, and 'false' if the elements has a value

Issue: I came up with below solution but its giving me only one value as true instead of checking for each value of array , please help in correcting below code:

Code:

def check_nill(array1)

p = Proc.new{ |num| num.nil?}

c = array1.any?(&p)

return c

end

array1 = [2,nil,8]

result = check_nill(array1)

puts "#{ result1 }"

Output: true

Comment: A likely duplicate of this question: [How can I create a Proc to checking whether the elements of an array are nil or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72255368/1301972)

Answer (score 1):

Create a Proc to check if a value is a nil or not.

```
my_proc = Proc.new { |num| num.nil? }
```

Iterate over the array using the above proc

```
array1 = [2,nil,8]
array1.map { |x| my_proc.call(x) }
```

You will get the below result

```
[false, true, false]
```

Comment: A few other notes: 1) Methods that require no arguments can be turned into lambdas (special type of Proc) using `Symbol#to_proc` e.g. `my_proc = :nil?.to_proc`. 2) Procs can be passed as blocks using the "to_proc" syntax `&proc_reference` (also works for symbols using `Symbol#to_proc` e.g.  `array1.map(&my_proc)` or `array1.map(&:nil?)`

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, it gave me anew insight on procs, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't work because the method you're using, `Array#any?`, returns true if **any** of the values in the array is `nil` (due to your `p`). What I understood is that you want a solution that will return if each element is `nil` or not.

A possible solution is:

```
# You can create a Proc `p` that'll map an array to the results of `nil?`.
p = Proc.new { |ary| ary.map(&:nil?) } 

# You can apply a Proc by using the method `call`, or by doing:
#   p.([1, nil, 2])
#   p[[1, nil, 2]]
p.call([1, nil, 2]) # => [false, true, false]
```